# Give all <div>s inside a <div> a margin-bottom of 10px

Tags: html, css

How do I give all `<div>'s` inside a named `<div>` a `margin-bottom:10px;` instead of giving each one a `margin-bottom:10px;`

I have:

```
<div class="main">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div> //How can I give these 3 a margin-bottom:10px;
</div>
```

I did: `.main div {margin-bottom:10px;}` but that did not work.

Comment: Uh, your solution works. http://jsfiddle.net/rEj2F/. Check to see if there's other style rules being applied to your elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, in your css:

```
.main div{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is just what I did, but I wonder why mine did not work!

Comment: The OP has already used this, its in his question. Something else is wrong. Maybe a typo or something.